# Are Cardassian necks asymmetric?

Tags: aliens, star-trek-ds9, star-trek

I've always been under the impression there may be some asymmetry in their necks.

[image]

It's never been clear to me whether it really exists, or is just a matter of camera angle or lighting or my imagination.

## Are Cardassian necks actually asymmetric?

Comment: In both of these photos, the actor is looking to the side, which also makes our own necks lose symmetry. How are we meant to judge? The question is interesting, but I'm not sure it has much basis. Are there more convincing photos of the supposed effect?

Comment: @underscore_d, the reason I used the Damar one is because it's the clearest picture I could find where the torso and head are nearly straight on and the head is barely tilted. I haven't been able to find another good example, and I don't know if I have the patience to go take a good screencap.

Comment: ... I believe this is a good example because despite the  (small) rotation and tilt of the head, the asymmetry is quite pronounced.

Comment: "Find another example" meant "find another image in so neutral a position by Googling"

Comment: Actually, image-googling for "Cardassian" gives me all kinds of suitable photos - just that most, if not all of them (e.g. [this](http://startrek-forever-rpg.wdfiles.com/local--files/legate-levat/legate2.jpg), or [this](https://startrekblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/joret_dal.png?w=627)) let the necks appear pretty symmetrical

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I don't agree that your first one is obviously symmetrical.

Comment: Humans are Asymmetric... most creatures are... why not the Cardassians?

Answer (score 11):

There do appear to be mild asymmetries in Cardassian necks, such as in Damar's in your question and in Dukat's below:

[image]

There is a slight tilt to Damar's head and a more dramatic tilt in Dukat's, which could be responsible for the slight differences in shape between the two sides of each of their necks.  What I think is more significant is the number and size of ridges on the two sides.  **In the screen capture above, Damar's neck has 8 ridges on one side and 5 on the other.  Dukat's has 7 on one side and 4 on the other.**  Even if the angle obscures some of the ridges on one side, there are clear size differences, in both subjects.

**All of this being said, there does not seem to be an acknowledgement or explanation of any neck asymmetry, official or otherwise.  (You may very well have been the first person to comment on it publicly.)**

Out-of-universe, I suspect it is a planned feature of the makeup work / neck prosthetic, especially given that it happens in more than one Cardassian. Intentional asymmetry would line up well with a possible in-universe reason: that it is a kind of harmless naturally-occurring variation, such as having more skin moles on one side of one's body than the other, or an eye that is positioned slightly differently than the other:

> **CRUSHER:** Your right eye is .004 higher than your left.
>
> **PICARD:** Nobody's perfect, Doctor.

(From ["Unification" Part 1](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/208.htm))

Comment: "Out-of-universe, I suspect it is a mere defect in the makeup work / neck prosthetic" -- or, you know, a mask builder who knows their craft. Humans are not symmetric, so symmetric aliens would probably look weird to us. Weirder than the TV folks want them to be, at least.

Comment: @Raphael: Interestingly enough, increasing symmetry (generally by mirror sides in a photograph) actually increases perception of beauty, with the main theory being that genetic defects increase asymmetry, so people with more symmetrical features are more genetically fit.

Comment: For the same reason I mentioned above - both characters looking to the side - it could be that the prosthetics are designed perfectly well and symmetrical, and sufficiently realistic that they bend and flex just like our own necks. I wouldn't be quite so quick to blame the make-up department here.

Comment: This picture of Dukat is iffy.   The reason I used the Damar one is because it's the clearest picture I could find where the torso and head are nearly straight on and the head is barely tilted.  I haven't been able to find another good example,  and I don't know if I have the patience to go take a good screencap.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Look at the ridges themselves.  There's more smaller ones on his right (our left)

Comment: @Izkata, that's a great observation and the makings of a great answer!

Comment: @ThePopMachine : The number and size of the ridges is exactly what I was referring to in my Dukat screenshot, not the shape of the two sides, which could be a tiling issue only.  I'm going to make this clear.

Comment: @Praxis, yep,  got it